# Mixing MyISAM and innoDB Table in MySQL transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions

In following code:

```
BEGIN
     DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception, not found
     BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;                  
     END;
     START TRANSACTION;
          INSERT INTO InnoDBTable
          VALUES(...);
          -- some code here          
          INSERT INTO MyISAMTable
          VALUES(...);
          -- some other code
     COMMIT;
END;
```

I want to know that if sqlexception occurs in transaction, what will happen to table having MyISAM engine as I know MyISAM don't support transactions. Will changes in both tables will be rollbacked? or changes in InnoDBTable will be rollbacked and changes in MyISAM table will be saved?

Comment: It comes directly from horse's mouth.  

"only changes in innodb table will be rolled back"

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM does not support transaction. So if you mix myISAM and InnoDB in a transaction , then on rollback myISAM changes will not be reverted.